# Как поставить границы ввода в pascal

Tags: pascal

Нужно,чтобы переменная Y не была больше 10000

```
program text;

var
  y,p:real;
begin
  write('Введите данные переменной y ');
  readln(y);
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Нужно проверять, что ввел пользователь. И если он ввел некорректное значение, то сообщать об ошибке и, может быть, просить ввести опять.

```
program text;

var
  y,p:real;
begin
  repeat
    write('Введите данные переменной y ');
    readln(y);
  until y <= 10000;  {Выходим из цикла если выполнится условие y <= 10000}
end.
```

Или так

```
program text;

var
  y,p:real;
begin
  write('Введите данные переменной y ');
  readln(y);
  while y > 10000 do begin { Пока y > 10000 крутим цикл }
    write('Вы ввели слишком большое значение. Попробуйте еще раз ');
    readln(y);
  end;
end.
```